# Need to put style-tag in head section in XPages, output goes to Excel

Tags: java, xpages

I have an XPage that allows the selection of a query-document. The full-text query that's inside it searches documents from the database, does some calculations and displays them as a view on the screen. There is also a button on the screen that sets requestScope.showExcel=true and does a full reload, in order to download the data directly into Excel (using .setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; myfile.xls"). It is no more than a simple table with its tr and td tags. So far so good.

Column properties (height, width, colour) can be set per column, these are stored inside the query-document (which is a separate document, not part of the search results). Those properties are put into a style-tag element created using an xp:text control set to create html output.

It all works, except for one thing: Excel and OpenOffice or LibreOffice Calc don't like the style section in the body. When I save the output and move the styles to the head section the file loads okay in Excel.

So I went out to put our computed styling in the head section. I found the styleSheet resource, with its computed content parameter. It does generate some of the CSS I put in, but not all. As it turns out, the content is computed on load, and not dynamically. The button mentioned above does a full refresh of the page, which made me assume that styles would also be updated.

Alas, no. The stylesheet content seems to be fixed.

My questions:

- Is there a way that inline CSS can be put in a style section in the head section in a dynamic way, so that it is recomputed when the page is reloaded (full update)?
- Is there maybe some control somewhere that lets me add arbitrary content to the head section?
- Or is there a way in Java to dynamically adapt the head section??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Never used it myself but have a look at the `xp:headTag` tag. Example here: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1181

Comment: @MarkLeusink Thanks. Tried that one, but it doesn't allow content (or I don't know how to set it). I'll try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your own renderer for your header resource:

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages.renderkit;

import com.ibm.commons.util.StringUtil;
import com.ibm.xsp.complex.Parameter;
import com.ibm.xsp.render.ResourceRenderer;
import com.ibm.xsp.resource.GenericHeadResource;
import com.ibm.xsp.resource.Resource;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.JSUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;

public class GenericHeadResourceRenderer extends ResourceRenderer {
    public void encodeResource(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uiComponent,
            Resource res) throws IOException {
        GenericHeadResource headRes = (GenericHeadResource) res;
        ResponseWriter rw = fc.getResponseWriter();

        String tagName = headRes.getTagName();
        if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(tagName)) {

            rw.startElement(tagName, uiComponent);

            List<Parameter> params = headRes.getAttributes();
            if (params != null) {
                for (Parameter param : params) {
                    String name = param.getName();
                    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(name)) {
                        String value = param.getValue();
                        if (value == null) {
                            value = "";
                        }
                        if( "content".equals( name ) ){
                            rw.write( value );
                        }else{
                            rw.writeAttribute(name, value, name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            rw.endElement(tagName);
            JSUtil.writeln(rw);
        }
    }
}
```

To activate the renderer, you have to overwrite the existing one in the *faces-config.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="1.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>com.ibm.xsp.resource.Resource</component-family>
            <renderer-type>com.ibm.xsp.resource.GenericHead</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>ch.hasselba.xpages.renderkit.GenericHeadResourceRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>

</faces-config>
```

Then, add the dynamic content you want in a parameter with the name "*content*":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

     <xp:this.resources>
         <xp:headTag tagName="style">
             <xp:this.attributes>
                 <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/css" />
                 <xp:parameter name="content"
                    value="#{javascript:java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()}" />
             </xp:this.attributes>
         </xp:headTag>
    </xp:this.resources>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: Good Lord, it works! Happy, amazed, in awe, and also kind of sad, because it's something I'd never have found myself. Now I have to find something to disable the generation of all dojo-related junk that I don't need in the Excel file... Vielen Dank!!